# Collapse two queries into a single one

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I have the following entities in my Neo4J database (using version 2.0).

```
Target
Library
Function
```

These are the relationships among each.

```
function[:used_in]->target
function[:included_in]->library
library[:part_of]->target
```

My ultimate goal is to construct a tree in C# that allows me to express the mapping between the Function(s) that are used in a Target, but with a way to relate them back to their originating Library. In the tree, the Library would be expressed as a parent node of the Function.

In other words, let's say a Library exposes 10 different functions, but only 5 of them are consumed by(used_in) a given Target. I'm only interested in those 5 and not the rest. On a per-function basis, I want to be able to quickly (in my tree) get to the Library that "includes" the given function. I have the collection of Targets and understand that I will most likely have to issue a separate query for each Target. My goal is to avoid issuing multiple queries for each Target/Library/Function.

Given the relationships that I have described, is it possible to construct a Cypher query that will return me the nodes of interest?

Here is the Cypher query that will return all of the functions for a given target.

```
MATCH (function:Function)-[:used_in]->(target:Target)
WHERE (target.Name = "target.exe")
RETURN function
```

Here is the Cypher query that will return the Library for a given function.

```
MATCH (function:Function)-[:included_in]->(library:Library)
WHERE (function.Name = "foo")
RETURN library
```

I'm interested to see if this can be combined into a single query. In my current scenario, I would need to run the second query for every Function. I am hopeful that my relationships are optimal enough to allow me to reduce the number of queries that I need to make.

I am using Neo4JClient - if someone helps to provide the Cypher query, I am hopeful that I can translate it to Neo4JClient. If someone goes even further and gives me the C# code, all the better, but please help me understand the Cypher behind it.

Here is the Cypher to construct the database:

```
CREATE (t:Target { Name: 'Target.exe' })
CREATE (t:Target { Name: 'Target2.exe' })
CREATE (t:Target { Name: 'Target3.exe' })
CREATE (l:Library { Name: 'Library.lib', Path: 'i386' })
CREATE (l:Library { Name: 'Library.lib', Path: 'amd64' })
CREATE (l:Library { Name: 'Library2.lib', Path: 'amd64' })
CREATE (f:Function { Name: 'FunctionA' })
CREATE (f:Function { Name: 'FunctionB' })
CREATE (f:Function { Name: 'FunctionC' })
CREATE (f:Function { Name: 'FunctionZ' })

MATCH (f:Function),(l:Library) WHERE (f.Name = "FunctionA") AND (l.Name = "Library.lib") AND (l.Path = "amd64") CREATE f-[:included_in]->l
MATCH (f:Function),(l:Library) WHERE (f.Name = "FunctionB") AND (l.Name = "Library.lib") AND (l.Path = "amd64") CREATE f-[:included_in]->l
MATCH (f:Function),(l:Library) WHERE (f.Name = "FunctionC") AND (l.Name = "Library2.lib") AND (l.Path = "amd64") CREATE f-[:included_in]->l
MATCH (f:Function),(l:Library) WHERE (f.Name = "FunctionZ") AND (l.Name = "Library.lib") AND (l.Path = "i386") CREATE f-[:included_in]->l
MATCH (f:Function),(l:Library) WHERE (f.Name = "FunctionZ") AND (l.Name = "Library.lib") AND (l.Path = "amd64") CREATE f-[:included_in]->l

MATCH (f:Function),(t:Target) WHERE (f.Name = "FunctionA") AND (t.Name = "Target.exe") CREATE f-[:used_in]->t
MATCH (f:Function),(t:Target) WHERE (f.Name = "FunctionB") AND (t.Name = "Target.exe") CREATE f-[:used_in]->t
MATCH (f:Function),(t:Target) WHERE (f.Name = "FunctionC") AND (t.Name = "Target2.exe") CREATE f-[:used_in]->t
MATCH (f:Function),(t:Target) WHERE (f.Name = "FunctionZ") AND (t.Name = "Target3.exe") CREATE f-[:used_in]->t

MATCH (l:Library),(t:Target) WHERE (l.Name = "Library.lib") AND (l.Path ="amd64") AND (t.Name = "Target.exe") CREATE l-[:part_of]->t
MATCH (l:Library),(t:Target) WHERE (l.Name = "Library2.lib") AND (l.Path ="amd64") AND (t.Name = "Target2.exe") CREATE l-[:part_of]->t
MATCH (l:Library),(t:Target) WHERE (l.Name = "Library.lib") AND (l.Path ="i386") AND (t.Name = "Target3.exe") CREATE l-[:part_of]->t
```

For those interested, here is the Neo4Client code that I used based on the Cypher query that Wes provided.

```
var query = graphClient.Cypher
.Match("(function:Function)-[:used_in]->(target:Target),(function:Function)-[:included_in]->(library:Library)")
.Where((Target target) => target.Name == sourceTarget.Name)
.AndWhere((Target target) => target.Path == sourceTarget.Path)
.AndWhere((Target target) => target.PEType == sourceTarget.PEType)
.AndWhere((Target target) => target.FileArch == sourceTarget.FileArch)
.AndWhere((Library library) => library.Name == sourceLibrary.Name)
.AndWhere((Library library) => library.Path == sourceLibrary.Path)
.AndWhere((Library library) => library.PEType == sourceLibrary.PEType)
.AndWhere((Library library) => library.FileArch == sourceLibrary.FileArch)
.Return((function) => new
{
    Functions = function.CollectAs<Function>()
})
.Results
.Select(result => new FunctionCollection()
{
    Collection = result.Functions.Select(a => a.Data).ToList()
});
```

Comment: it would be great if you could give us an example graph, either with create statements or in console.neo4j.org.

Comment: Thanks Wes. I will try to come up with the minimal set of statements and provide them. Is there any way to paste a bunch of Cypher statements into the Console at once? I resorted to copy/paste, and that was painful when I realized I needed to start over.

Comment: You've got to do one at a time in console. :(

Comment: I've added the statements above. I could not share the link because it would not allow me to add the initial Cypher statements. I guess you can always just do them 1-by-1 as well, but it's painful. Since the query below works, there's no need now, but added for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's too easy, but is it as simple as something like this? Please provide more info if not.

```
MATCH (function:Function)-[:used_in]->(target:Target),
      (function:Function)-[:included_in]->(library:Library)
WHERE (target.Name = "target.exe")
RETURN function, library
```

Comment: Thanks Wes. When I ran your query against my real data, it produced a case where it gave me two "libraries" back with the same name, but a different "path" property. I need to confirm that the data is being inserted into the db properly as I'm not sure if this is a bug in my insertion code or not. When I tried to mock the scenario using the console with fake data, I did not reproduce the problem. I'll reply back after I double check everything. Thanks again.

Comment: This appears to be working, although I now understand where my confusion was coming from. I will need to alter both the Library and Target nodes with an additional property that allows me to filter down on a specific attribute at query time. I really appreciate the help. I will mark this is as the answer and will try to figure out how to translate this into C#. If you can help, that would be great.

Comment: You can potentially use properties on other nodes to filter--can you describe what you mean? Might be good to put it in a new question.

Comment: Thanks Wes. I got this working and it's so much better than what I was using previously. I'm down from 6 minutes to less than a minute to compose the tree. I tightened up the objects so that they have more distinct properties and then I ensured that the objects were related through the property. My problem is that I was not able to be specific enough in my queries, and it lead to duplicates. The Cypher that you provided works great.

Comment: In C#, the key part you need is just to extend your Return call with the extra column: Return((function, library) => new { Function = function.As<Function>(), Library = library.As<Library>() })

Comment: If you can't get the Cypher to C# conversion right, please open it as a new question. It's impossible to format anything useful in the comments here.